# Order object hold a Customer object or the customers ID or both?

Tags: php, oop

If I have an `Order` object and each `Order` has a `Customer` what should the `Order` object hold, a `Customer` object or the customers ID or both?

Does it depend on the context or since we are dealing with objects in OOP the `Order` should ideally hold a `Customer` object and not just its ID like the database column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not mix db thinking with PHP code design.. Regulary the property should be set to the object itself rather then to its id. Like this:

```
class Order {

    /**
     * @var Contact
     */
    protected $contact;


    public function __construct(Contact $contact) {
        $this->contact = $contact;
    }

}
```

But there are reasons when it might make sense to just have to id of the contact. The best example would be that the contact has to be fetched from database, but you regulary don't need its information, expect of special cases. Then it might be useful to only have the id as class property and fetch the contact if required. (Known as 'lazy loading'). Note that 'lazy loading' could be hidden behind the scenes by a framework.